# JSON Data Access Objects

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JSON returned from an AJAX call:

```
{"rows":[{"Date":"07/10/2011","Value":1206,"Action":"Drink"},    
{"Date":"07/11/2011","Value":2288,"Action":"Pie"},
{"Date":"07/12/2011","Value":1070,"Action":"Drink"},
{"Date":"07/13/2011","Value":1535,"Action":"Beer"},
{"Date":"07/14/2011","Value":1721,"Action":"Drink"}],
"page":1,"total":1,"records":5}
```

How can I get values from this result using jQuery?

For instance, I'd like to get data elements for the first row:

```
json.rows[0].date = 07/10/2011
json.rows[0].value = 1206
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, you could use eval() but eval() is generally considered evil, plus JSON is not *exactly* the same as a defining data in Javascript code.  I just googled which reminded me that jquery has a parseJSON function.

Check it out.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

But if you are using jquery for the ajax ( pretty popular ), you can set the dataType to json and this will do it for you.

```
    $.ajax(
    {
            url: "/map", // should return JSON
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {},
            success: function(response)
            {
                // response is an object

                alert( response.rows[0].Date );

                cook( response );
            }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am looking to use AJAX but just wondering how I actually get each row of data as an object ? i.e. if my data above is `response` do I simply `var obj = response;` and then use `obj.rows[0].Date` ?

Comment: yes, i think so, I have updated my answer, I hope it helps you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Little confused how to use this ? i.e. if my data above is `data` do I simply `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` and then use `obj.rows[0].data` ?

Comment: Not sure about `$.parseJSON` but this works pretty well: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(yourData); alert(obj.rows[0].Date);`

Comment: OK thanks - and to iterate across each line ? i.e. so I can get each piece of data - how would I do this ?

Comment: Well, `for (var i=0;i<obj.rows.length;i++) { alert(obj.rows[i].Date); }`

Comment: dont't forget to catch errors..  try { var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(yourData); } catch(e){ ... }